# CDK plus manual intervention

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I need to resize some subnets. I am using the `Vpc` construct to manage my VPC. I have made the changes to my CDK code to remove the too-small subnets and replace them with fewer-but-larger subnets. When I run `cdk diff` the diff shows that the existing too-small subnets will be removed and new, larger, subnets will be provisioned. But when I run `cdk deploy` it tries to first create the new subnets and that fails because the old subnets still exist.

I can't help but wonder if I were to manually eliminate those subnets and then re-run `cdk deploy` would it be smart enough to know those resources were deleted out of band and would then remove them and their dependencies from the stack and would the new subnets be able to be deployed properly?

Comment: Do you have any resources in the VPC? You will not be able to delete subnets with ENIs in them.

Comment: The subnets I want to replace have been cleared of resources.

Comment: Yes, deleting them by hand should work. Cloudformation would likely complain during the update cleanup phase, but should not be an issue.